# undefined method gotoAndPlay

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, simplebutton

I am not sure why every time I reword this code to do the same thing I usually get the error dealing with gotoAndPlay. Does it have to be a Movieclip because when I change it to a MovieClip an error occurs saying it needs to be extended as a Simple Button because that's what it is defined as. basically.

Error Codes:

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay.

```
 package 
 { 
     import flash.display.SimpleButton;
     import flash.events.Event;
     import flash.events.MouseEvent;
     import flash.display.MovieClip;

     public class search_button extends SimpleButton 
     { 
         public function Search_button()
         { 
             addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
         }
         function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
         { 
             trace("goto frame 9");
             gotoAndPlay("Search");
         }
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Where is "Search" frame label placed? At the main timeline?

Comment: yeah, it's placed on a layer just for labels on the Timeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
gotoAndPlay("Search");
```

with

```
(root as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay("Search");
```

because `search_button` doesn't have a frame with the "Search" label. The `root` is a main timeline.

Comment: oh By The Way, I had to Change Search_button to search_button in order for the function to actually happen, Just for anyone who one day looks onto this code for Help, Thanks